# Connect to SQL Server database (on AWS-RDS) as admin

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've instantiated a SQL Server database using Amazon's RDS tool.

What I want to to generally, is to `bulk insert` some csv files.

When I connect with the masteruser, I have almost no permissions (e.g no permissions to grant permissions in the database server)

> SQL Error [15247] [S0001]: User does not have permission to perform
>   this action.   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: User
>   does not have permission to perform this action.

When I run `select current-user` I get `GUEST`.

How can I change to admin?

Comment: According to this, bulk insert is not supported, although your error messages implies its just security, and this might be out of date. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html I'm curious about `select current-user` - that's not sql I am familiar with

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid according this documentation, bulk is not supported in sql server 2012, while I chose 2014, and it's not stated there. Therefore, I  suppose it's supported. Anyway, how can I grant myself this permission? what other ways I have to upload a file?